# Android Studio text all caps is not working

Tags: android

[ScreenShot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bygzp5dy83q687e/Screenshot%202017-06-26%2016.38.47.jpg?dl=0)

As you can see my text all caps property is not ticked, my design tool window shows text in lower case but my emulator does not. The same thing is happening with my phone. Please help.

Here are my xml code:
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ishansrivastava.a01_06_05_displaying_images_again.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/reusable_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="366dp"
        android:layout_height="304dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/levels"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Plain"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:onClick="onButton2Click"
        android:text="Search the Web"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/include"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:textAllCaps="false" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

reusable_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/content_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pepperoni" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Extra Cheese" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Show Image"
        tools:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Standard button style ...

Comment: Please share your xml code

Comment: edited question and added code @SunishaSindhu

Comment: tools:textAllCaps="false" change this in to android:textAllCaps="false"

Comment: thank you @SunishaSindhu it is working now. how can I set that to default when using design tool?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: The `android-studio` tag is **irrelevant**. Please stop adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tools:textAllCaps="false" change this in to android:textAllCaps="false"
```

For your another comment,please check with this,

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

The button text might be transformed to uppercase by your app's theme that applies to all buttons. Check your themes / styles files for setting the attribute android:textAllCaps.

Comment: sorry but I am a beginner and I don't know exactly where to find the themes/styles files

Comment: Okay.just go to app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml. There you can set

Comment: Thank you I did those changes and changed android back to tools and it is working now. Will I have to do this in each project?

Comment: According to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your button

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

if it don't work than try this my friend than this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I changed tools to android. I wonder why it does not do that by default when using the design tool

Comment: yeah sure but I will have to wait a certain amount of time before this site lets me accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});

Comment: In the layout XML, you can set the android:textAllCaps attribute on your TextView:
<TextView android:textAllCaps="true"></TextView>

or programatically you can do like this:
textView.isAllCaps = true

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34672885)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in theme, I have set

```
<style name="TextAppearance.WD.Headline6" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
    ...
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

But in one widget, I need to get every other attributes of Headline6 except textAllCaps attr.

So I am using in that widget as,

```
<TextView
...
android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
android:textAllCaps="false"
.../>
```

But that won't work, the theme attribute overrides the layout attribute and the widget shows all the text in caps.

The solution is to apply the attribute through code as,

```
binding.textViewHeadline6.isAllCaps = false
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

Attributes like

android:inputType,
android:SingleLine

nullifies effect of textAllCaps.

Take note

Comment: just going through same problem. discovered this. textAllCaps is allergic to some attributes like these. :)